# Internet Explorer does not prompt for windows authentication after session timeout

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, ssrs-2008, windows-authentication

I have a problem with SSRS Report Manager web application(but again I see this more as a typical ASP.Net application issue as well).

This application is configured to use the Windows Authentication and users typically acess the application using Internet Explorer. The application also has the session timeout setup for 20 minutes.

The issue (which has be interpreted as Information security issue :( ) is that, if the user is idle on this application for more than 20 minutes, he can still come back and continue working with any problem. They said that it's not timing out at all as they do not get the Login prompt.

When I run the Fiddler, I observed that first request after 20 minutes, is in-fact 401 that means, server has declined the request. After that, I believe, Internet Explorer sents the cached credentials. Because of this the Login Prompt does not appear.

The questions I have is these
1. Is it true that the IE can send cached credentials after session is timed out? Any Microsoft Link/reference?
2. Is there any way we could force the login dialog to come after session timed out? (I removed from IE settings tab and advaced tab but no luck)

Comment: Do the users see a login prompt when they first start your application then? They shouldn't if you're using Windows Authentication...

Comment: They do see that when they start the application.

Comment: That's weird. Do they use the same userid to log in to windows as to log into your app? Have you got Internet Explorer configured to prevent credentials being automatically supplied?

Comment: Yes they do use the same userid to login to the windows as to log into the app. And Yes on the Internet explorer settings, I have changed settings at two places 1. Internet Options -> Security -> Cusom Level -> Prompt for Username and password . 2. Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security -> Uncheck windows authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is a very [good blog-post](http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2005/04/12/14.aspx) discussing a few different options, but the best one is to get your application to detect the session timeout and send a 401 response code.

An alternative (and better) approach is to not use Windows Authentication, and to implement your own login interface. This is pretty straight-forward in ASP.NET.

If you do not have control of your application, and it sounds like you don't, then there is not a lot you can do.

**However**, that doesn't explain what you are trying to achieve by forcing the user to login manually, and re-login if their session expires. The only time that you would gain anything from forcing the user to log-in to your web-site manually is if you expected them to leave their computer unlocked - but then you already have a gaping security hole anyway. It's like winding up the windows in your car, but then leaving the doors unlocked and the key on the roof.

Comment: I totally understand what you mentioned and to certain extent I agree. However, this application being SSRS Application, it's developed by microsoft itself so I dont have much control to it's inside except few configuration steps. And the reason why I need that is that it's being viewed and Security Policy exception (which I have not control on) and I needed someway to enforce user to login. Do you have any reference/links from Microsoft which states that it will *always* work like that itself (I mean IE will always send credentials by itself and supress the prompt).

Comment: Another thing to note here is that, as I mentioned the application DOES send the 401 code (fiddler told me) however instead of prompting for a dialog, it comes with default credentials.

Comment: The 401 is being sent because IE will *always* try to login anonymously first. This is rejected at the IIS layer. If your application also send a 401 then IE will open a login prompt.

Comment: And, with respect, what you've get their is a stupid information security requirement. It's nonsensical. I suspect they don't understand what windows authentication is and youre best bet is to try and educate them.

Comment: Finally, if it's any help, please read http://support.microsoft.com/?id=264921. It discusses how IE will resend credentials. Unfortunately, it says per-session, but I think it means IE session, not IIS session.

Comment: Great, it helps to certain extent. Yeah I also thing, session there means IE session so it makes sense. Thanks for your help